# Ask about a particular java collections having following properties

Tags: java, collections

I want to ask about collection that i can use in my project. The following are my requirements.

1. **It have key-value pair.**
   One is mobile field and other is distance.
2. **mobile field is unique but distance is not unique.**
3. **It should store them as ascending order of distance field.**
4. **I do not want dupicates distance(key-pair) to be removed.**

   I have already tried to use `TreeMap` taking distance as key and mobile as value.

   But it is removing the duplicates. And I can not also make mobile as key because, 
   otherwise it will sort the pair according to the value of mobile. so please tell what to do.

   ```
   TreeMap tree = new TreeMap();
   while(rs.next()){  
   // obtaining dist and mob values here
       tree.put(dist, mob);
   }
   Set set=tree.entrySet();  
   Iterator itr=set.iterator();  
   out.println("distance   " + "mobile");
   while(itr.hasNext()){  
       Map.Entry m=(Map.Entry)itr.next();  
       out.println(m.getKey()+"   "+m.getValue()+"\n");  
   }
   ```

I want to get all mobile numbers in the order of their corresponding increasing distances. This is what i have tried so far , but the problem with this is it is eliminating duplicate distances.

Comment: No sorry, mobile field is already unique. But their corresponding distances can be repeated.

Comment: `It should store them as ascending order of distance field` I don't understand. Field is key, distance is value, and you want it sorted (in a particular way) for both? Please elaborate, and maybe show your attempt to help give me an idea of what you're doing

Comment: What operations do you intend to perform

Comment: @VinceEmigh i have edited the question.. plss help..

Comment: @arunmoezhi  i have edited the question.. plss help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same TreeMap with the parameter as

```
TreeMap<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>> tMap=new TreeMap<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>>();
```

Here consider the distance as key and mobileNo as value. As per your statement, for the same distance there are several mobileNo value (Since distance is not unique). So for the value field we can have LinkedList or ArrayList.

TreeMap will store the keys in a sorted manner. So you can print the TreeMap based on the key and all values for the key.

Complete code is given below,

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class MultiValueCollection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MultiValueCollection mCollection=new MultiValueCollection();
        TreeMap<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>> tMap=new TreeMap<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>>();


        mCollection.addMobileNumberByDistance(tMap, 40, 65655423);
        mCollection.addMobileNumberByDistance(tMap, 40, 76785647);
        mCollection.addMobileNumberByDistance(tMap, 40, 85785852);
        mCollection.addMobileNumberByDistance(tMap, 40, 96786344);
        mCollection.addMobileNumberByDistance(tMap, 40, 57657354);

        mCollection.addMobileNumberByDistance(tMap, 20, 13543353);
        mCollection.addMobileNumberByDistance(tMap, 20, 23453456);

        mCollection.addMobileNumberByDistance(tMap, 30, 33353544);
        mCollection.addMobileNumberByDistance(tMap, 30, 43534554);
        mCollection.addMobileNumberByDistance(tMap, 30, 59789785);


        mCollection.printMobileNumbersByDistance(tMap);
    }

    public void addMobileNumberByDistance(TreeMap<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>> tMap, int distance, int mobileNo)
    {
        LinkedList<Integer> list=null;
        if(tMap.get(distance)==null)
        {
            list=new LinkedList<Integer>();
        }else
        {
            list=tMap.get(distance);
        }
        list.push(mobileNo);
        tMap.put(distance, list);
    }

    public void printMobileNumbersByDistance(TreeMap<Integer,LinkedList<Integer>> distNumberMap)
    {
        LinkedList<Integer> list;
        for(int n : distNumberMap.keySet())
        {
            list=distNumberMap.get(n);
            Collections.sort(list);//Add this line if mobileNo needs to be sorted for a given distance
            for(int k : list)
            {
                System.out.println("key "+n+" value "+k);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep several values for each key, you need a `MultiMap`. Guava has several of them, including a couple that have sorted values. Take a look at [`TreeMultiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html) for example.

> *Implementation of Multimap whose keys and values are ordered by their natural ordering or by supplied comparators.*

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to implement this. Following is a way you might not have considered but could possibly work:

1) Define a new class that contains both the "key" and the "value" as instance fields.

2) Implement the Comparable interface, i.e., write your own rules for how to order, including how to handle tie breaks.

3) Use a collection that sorts via the Comparable.